# CMT transaction doesn't commit anything

Tags: hibernate, jakarta-ee, jboss, ejb, jta

i am using JBOSS HIBERNATE

i add these 2 properties in persistence.xml

```
  <property name="hibernate.transaction.manager_lookup_class"  
            value="org.hibernate.transaction.JBossTransactionManagerLookup"/>
   <property name="hibernate.transaction.factory_class"   
                      value="org.hibernate.transaction.CMTTransactionFactory"/>
```

and i add this above my method where i want to commit a row 
 @TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRES_NEW)

```
@Stateless
@Path("/")
class A
{
  @POST()
  @Path("abc")
  public String methodA()
  {
    this.methodB();
  }
}

class B
{
  //i add annotation here  i.e transactionalattribute
  public void methodB()
  {
    EntityManager em;
    em.persist("something in db");
  }
}
```

does any more configuration need to be done ??

i saw all stackoverflow related question doesn't find out my answer

does any jboss related setting needed ??

Comment: What kind of method did you add the attribute to?  That attribute only applies to EJB business methods (not non-EJB methods, and not non-business methods like private or methods directly called from other EJB methods).

Comment: i called a rest api function
and in the rest api service function, i called a class public function i add this annotation on that class method

Comment: When you say "class public function", do you mean a static method?  Do you call through a business interface or directly?  It would probably be easier if you can include a code snippet.

Comment: Thanks for the code snippet, but there are a few issues: (1) how does class B relate to class A? does class A extend B? (2) how is `em` initialized?  It would help if you included actual snippets from your application rather than typing a new example here; otherwise, it's difficult to give accurate suggestions.